# WebServiceContext remains null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-ws

I have two web services implemented with JAX-WS: `RequestService` and `ExtendedRequestService`.

`ExtendedRequestService` calls `RequestService` and adds additional data to the response.
When calling `RequestService`, the `WebServiceContext` is injected, but when calling it from `ExtendedRequestService`, it is null and the code throws a `NullPointerException`.

How can I properly initialize it?

This is how I call `RequestService` from `ExtendedRequestService`:

```
RequestServiceImpl requestService = new RequestServiceImpl();
RequestServiceResponse requestServiceResponse = requestService.performRequest(requestServiceRequest);
```

Comment: What application server are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but this seems to work properly:

Declare `WebServiceContext` like this in your service implementation:

```
private WebServiceContext wsContext;

@Resource
public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
    this.wsContext = context;
}
```

then when you need to call `RequestService` from your `ExtendedRequestService` use:

```
RequestServiceImpl requestService = new RequestServiceImpl();
requestService.setContext(wsContext); //The WebServiceContext of your ExtendedRequestService class
RequestServiceResponse requestServiceResponse = requestService.performRequest(requestServiceRequest);
```

Comment: After further testing, this solution seems to work flawlessly, therefore I'll accept my answer.